# Redirect after rewrite not working

Tags: apache, redirect

We have example1.com redirecting to example2.com - this works (also enforces ssl).

But we have a lot of links in the form of example1.com/dir/subdirectory that need to go to example2.com/dir/differentsubdirectory.

```
Redirect "/skill-catalog" "/catalog"

and

RewriteRule ^/home/skill-catalog/(.*)$ /home/catalog/$1 [R,L]
```

I have tried each and neither works.  What am I doing wrong or am I missing the order they need to be in?  Also would this be easier to do in htacess file for wordpress or how I am currently doing it - in the httpd conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/home/skill-catalog/(.*)$ https://example2.com/home/catalog/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This did not work.  Tried this before and after our main doman/ssl redirect.

Comment: Can you share the full content of .htaccess?